Firmware upgrades "fwupd" not working on Raspberry and MacBook Air 2014 - WARNING: UEFI capsule updates not available or enabled in firmware setup
I love to the idea of fwupd. But it's not working on both Ubuntu machines (Rasperry PI 5 and MacBook Air 2014).
I always get this error (all commands return the same error, fwupdmgr get-devices and fwupdmgr update and fwupdmgr refresh)
WARNING: UEFI capsule updates not available or enabled in firmware setup  
See https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/PluginFlag:capsules-unsupported for more information.  
Metadata is up to date; use --force to refresh again.  
WARNING: UEFI capsule updates not available or enabled in firmware setup  
See https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/PluginFlag:capsules-unsupported for more information.  
No updatable devices

How-To enable fwupd on those devices?
The GitHub wiki link in error message did not help. Is my hardware not compatible?

Neither the Raspberry Pi foundation nor Apple are uploading firmware to the LVFS. Neither are also using the standards-compliant UpdateCapsule mechanism for update, so the warning is essentially correct. If you plug in a USB device that is supported by fwupd then you'll be able to update that. See the list of supported hardware here: https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/
